# a closed form lower bound solution for linear programming

Tags: approximation-theory, linear-programming, implicit-function-theorem

Given a linear objective function and a system of linear constraints, is there any known closed form lower bounds for it?
to clearly express the problem assume that
$$
z(\mathbf{a,B,c})=\mathop {\inf} \left\{ {\bf{a^Tx} 
|\quad\bf{Bx-c}\le0} \right\}
$$
is any closed form (rather linear) function $y(\mathbf{a,B,c})$ versus $\mathbf{a,B,c}$  such that 
$y(\mathbf{a,B,c})\le z(\mathbf{a,B,c})$.

As I know,  any feasible dual solution for the above problem is a lower bound for it. However, the dual problem take the similar form of the primal problem. How can I obtain a close form lower bound for the above problem?

Comment: In that general form you should not expect a closed-form solution. That is precisely why there are several algorithms (simplex, ellipsoid and interior-point methods) for linear programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the dual. Any dual feasible solution will give you a lower bound, by weak duality (assuming your problem is feasible and not unbounded).